# Split a string variable into many and use scratch variables in SPSS

Tags: string, split, spss

I'm working with some data in SPSS and what I want to do is the following:

Compare each of the 45 letters inside two string variables. If they're equal, put 1 on another specific variable, if they're not, put 0.

Here's an example of how the string variables are:

http://postimg.org/image/py3g2a26x/

Here's on part of the code I'm trying to run:

```
COMPUTE #i = 1.
DO REPEAT Q = Q_CN_1 to Q_CN_45.
COMPUTE #a = substr(TX_RESPOSTAS_CN,#i,1).
COMPUTE #b = substr(DS_GABARITO_CN,#i,1).
DO IF (#a = #b).
COMPUTE Q = 1.
ELSE.
COMPUTE Q = 0.
END IF.
COMPUTE #i = #i+1.
END REPEAT.
```

Then I get returned the following error:

Error # 4309 in column 11. Text: (End of Command) Invalid combination
of data types in an assignment. Character strings may only be assigned
to string variables. Numeric and logical quantities may only be
assigned to numeric variables. Consider using the STRING or NUMBER
function. This command not executed.

Anybody know what am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the scratch variables to be matched as strings.

```
STRING #A #B (a1).
COMPUTE #i = 1.
DO REPEAT Q = Q_CN_1 to Q_CN_45.
COMPUTE #a = substr(TX_RESPOSTAS_CN,#i,1).
COMPUTE #b = substr(DS_GABARITO_CN,#i,1).
DO IF (#a = #b).
COMPUTE Q = 1.
ELSE.
COMPUTE Q = 0.
END IF.
COMPUTE #i = #i+1.
END REPEAT.
```

Comment: So simple, and I couldn't figure it out! Thank you!